# Upgrading to asp.net 4.5: The name [controlName] does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2013

We are moving an application from ASP.NET 2.0 to ASP.NET 4.5.  We were running VS 2k5 and now we're upgrading to VS 2k13 (w/ VSO/TFS).

I had some references to fix and some obsolete methods to fix.  Once I got everything done and fixed the last error in my post-build Error List I clicked build again and expected to finally have a successful build.

I got 18k errors.  All my pages are saying The name [control name] does not exist in the current context.

My code behind declarations all match my inherits tags in the aspx pages, they all have runat="server" in the form section.   I have no idea, it's like the aspx pages and the code behind pages are not wired together anymore.  This didn't happen until all the other errors were fixed/cleared.

Comment: In your .aspx file, are you using CodeBehind or CodeFile? If you're using CodeBehind, try change that to CodeFile.

Comment: I'm using CodeFile, not CodeBehind.  Typed it wrong above.

Answer (score 0):

•Right-click on the parent aspx file. In the pop-up menu, select Convert to Web Application.

I hope this will help you.. :)

Comment: I don't see this as an option, it's not in the context menu?  Using VS 2k13 Premium.  The application is an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Application project.